# Create class from xml file in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008

i have a xml file with following structure,

```
<TestClass>
  <TestChildClass>
    <TestName Name="sample">
      <Table Name="table1" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="Mark" CharColumn="Name" >
        <Table Name="table2" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="SubjectCode" CharColumn="Subject" ReferenceColumn ="RollNo" >
            <Table Name="table3" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="Average" CharColumn="Subject" ReferenceColumn ="SubjectCode"/>          
         </Table>

        <Table Name="table4" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="Rank" CharColumn="Name" />
      </Table >
    </TestName >    
  </TestChildClass>
  </TestClass>
```

i have created a class for the above xml using XSD.EXE. But the thing is when i tried to create object for the new class named TestClass.cs  then its throwing error like "The same table 'Table' cannot be the child table in two nested relations." How to solve this?

Comment: That's not an XSD file, you can't generate a class from it, because you can't be sure of everything about the definition from one example XML file.  If you know all the details, you can manually write the corresponding classes.

Comment: But we can create xsd file from xml using xsd.exe right?

Comment: From the XSD cmd line: `<instance>.xml     Name of an xml file to infer xsd schema from.`

Comment: ya.. i have created those classes. When i am trying to create instance for that created class it shows error

Comment: Your XML is not valid...

Comment: Then how to manipulate this kind of xml witout XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not valid, you need to remove the  lines and make sure to close the node for Table1

```
<TestClass>
  <TestChildClass>
    <TestName Name="sample">
      <Table Name="table1" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="Mark" CharColumn="Name" >
        <Table Name="table2" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="SubjectCode" CharColumn="Subject" ReferenceColumn ="RollNo" >
            <Table Name="table3" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="Average" CharColumn="Subject" ReferenceColumn ="SubjectCode"/>          
         </Table>
        <Table Name="table4" IdentityColumnName="RollNo" IntColumn="Rank" CharColumn="Name" />
      </Table >
    </TestName >    
  </TestChildClass>
</TestClass>
```

Comment: But the Table2 is the child table of the table1. And table3 is the child table of table2. Table4 is the again the child table of the table1. for that only i have added the xml like that.

Comment: Then you need to remove the `/>` at the end of table1 and table2, and replace them with `>`.  That should make the XML well formed, but it may still fail the XSD class generation

Comment: ya.. that is what i have added in my question. please Checkout

Comment: It's still not well formed, you're not closing TestChildClass or TestClass

Comment: oh.. sorry i missed "/". but even it is showing the same error

Comment: Using the XML above I was able to use XSD.exe to create an xsd file from the XML, from there I used that xsd file to generate a c# class

Comment: ya.. you are able to create instance for that C# class?